# GUI database client

Tags: gratis, linux, gui, ubuntu

I am looking for a GUI tool which lets me explore a databases.

MySQL AND postgres AND SQLite at least, if it supported others like Memcached, Redis and Mongodb would be nice.

For the relational databases, I want to:

- See Table names
- Show Table structures (column names and types)
- Show Table content
- Summary statistics (e.g. how many rows are in the table)
- Search content
- Execute queries myself

For Redis / memcached I would like to see the summary statistics and search for a key / see all available keys (paginated).

Comment: For which operating system? What's your budget? Please read [ask]

Answer (score 1):

A good free multi-platform multi-DBMS GUI tool is [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/).

It provides all the features in your bullet list: viewing tables, seeing row counts (both estimated for multiple tables and exact values for individual tables), and running custom SQL.  It even generates an ERD diagram for the database.

DBeaver supports MySQL/MariaDB, Postgres, SQLite, and others.  The Enterprise Edition, which is not free, supports MongoDB and Redis, but the Community Edition does not.

Comment: Could you explain why?  Links may die, so could you list some features which answer the question?